# Отправка сообщения aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Допустим, я создал бота. Начал с ним общение. Как я могу ботом отправлять себе сообщение, т.е, без использования хэндлеров, чтобы к примеру раз в какое-то время бот именно мне присылал сообщение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение, но я уверен, что это самое худшее из всех решений, что могли быть.

Буду рад, если подскажете, что-то элегантнее.

```py
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot

token = 'token'
bot = Bot(token)


async def gg():
    while True:
        await bot.send_message(id, msg)
        asyncio.sleep(10)


asyncio.run(gg())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from aiogram import Bot

token = 'token'
bot = Bot(token)


def send_message():
    bot.send_message(ВашID,text)


while True:
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(send_message, "interval", seconds=10)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

bot = Bot(token="your token")
chat_id = 'yours chat id'

dp = Dispatcher(bot)

async def send_message(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start(dp, send_message('Fuck It!'))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: ваш ответ не решает заданного автором вопроса `к примеру раз в какое-то время бот именно мне присылал сообщение`, к тому же, что означает `id` в `await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, id, text=message)`?

Comment: @ZxNuClear я думаю это сгенерированный ответ всем известной нейросетью