# Как написать Telegram бота отправляющий сообщения другому пользователю на Python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Мне надо написать телеграм-бота на python который отправляет сообщения определённому пользователю который запустил бота. Если кто знает как это сделать то напишите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1227191/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-aiogram

поможет, ну а вместо собственного user_id, вытаскивать ид нужного юзера из бд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Телеграм бот может написать только тем пользователям, которые сами начали с ним взаимодействовать. В этот момент начала работы с ботом следует запоминать пользователся, регистрировать у себя в БД и запоминать его user_id.

Когда потребуется написать конкретному пользователю, только логике вашего приложения известно какому, то достаёте этот user_id из БД и шлёте ему сообщение.

Если Это что-то вроде анонимного чата через бота, то логически делите пользователей на пары (На чаты), где оба user_id кэшируете в памяти приложения или каком-нибудь redis (для отказоустойчивости и адекватной скорости работы с памятью)