# Отправка сообщению в личку aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Мне нужно чтоб бот отправляй сообщение в личку когда ему кто-то написал в личное сообщение

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отправка сообщения aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1227191/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-aiogram)

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая, что Вы не конкретизировали Ваш вопрос, я сочту его формулировку следующей: "как реализовать отправление сообщения от бота мне, если в бота кто-либо написал". Для этого, Вам необходимо сделать хендлер (dp.message или router.message, в зависимости от версии aiogram), который принимает сообщения и пользователей, а уже внутри функции, на которой поставите хендлер, реализуйте отправку сообщения по заданной константе Вашего ID:

```
CONSTANT_USER_ID = 12345678 # айди, кому необходимо отправлять уведомление

@router.handler()
async def some_function(message: Message, bot: Bot)
   ...
   await bot.send_message(chat_id=CONSTANT_USER_ID, text='ТЕКСТ УВЕДОМЛЕНИЯ'
```

Comment: Спасибо вам помогли

Comment: Отметьте тогда, пожалуйста, что Вы приняли мое сообщение за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу чёткого вопроса, предполагаю вы хотите чтобы бот отправлял сообщение при комманде старт.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def starting(message: types.Message):
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "hello")
```